# Nintex choice control rule

Tags: validation, checkbox, rule, nintex-workflow, multiplechoicefield

Any help would be highly appreciated.I am working on Nintex form and currently stuck with this rule to be worked.
I have first checkbox as YES/NO [(Name: NA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R4dT.jpg), trying to create a rule where automatically all the options (Name:Options) below automatically go uncheck when somebody clicks on this first "Not Applicable". If it could hide all the below options after clearing that would be great but not requirement. Definitely clearing them out is requirement.

Is there anyone who can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to see some screenshots of your form and it's controls.

However, I can tell you that a rule will not be able to change the values of another control. For this, you're going to want to use JavaScript in the Settings -> Custom JavaScript section.

I will often show/hide a portion of a form based on the selection of a control. And, when the section is hidden, I always want to clear out any data that may have been entered into those (now hidden) fields.

Here's an example:
[Image of Form Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfo2G.png)

And here's the code:

```
NWF$('#' + myYesNo).change(function(){    
    NWF$('#' + myChoices + ' input').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Every time the Yes/No field is checked, everything in the Choices field is unchecked.
I would also suggest adding a rule to the Choices field (and its label) that says `not(myYesNo)`: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUyuE.png).

If you didn't want to hide the choices, I would expand the JavaScript to test whether or not the Yes/No is currently true or false. However, hiding the choices entire remove the need for that test.